# Webpack resolve.alias breaks import of libraries prefixed with an @

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs

I am working on a Vue project where I'm attempting to use VuexORM. Upon initial install, I was getting an odd error:
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../uex-orm/core'`.

It should instead be `../@vuex-orm/core` (notice it's missing the @ and 'v' character).

I double-checked that I hadn't mistyped my imports. Then I realized that I'd implemented an alias so that I could import from the src/ directory with an @ symbol, which I believe explains the odd-looking import. I must have misconfigured my webpack or .babelrc (very possible because I suck at both).

How should I go about setting up my `webpack.config.js` and/or `.babelrc` so that I can both use an alias for imports as well as import libraries such as @vuex-orm?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              indentedSyntax: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  externals: {
    // global app config object
    config: JSON.stringify({
      apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    }),
  },
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
      "env",
      "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-root-import", {
      "rootPathSuffix": "src/",
      "rootPathPrefix": "@"
    }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the docs again for `babel-plugin-root-import` and either missed it or it was recently edited, but they mention:

> If you don't like the ~ syntax you can use your own symbol (for
>   example an # symbol or \ or anything you want). Using @ is not
>   recommended, as recent versions of NPM allow @ in package names. ~ is
>   the default since it's very unlikely to conflict with anything (and
>   wouldn't be expanded to HOME anyway).

So going through and changing my imports from `@/_components/User'` to `~/_components/User` works!

Hope this helps someone else!